# Возможно ли чтобы после введения в консоли n-ного символа массива программа автоматически запускалась (без Enter).

Tags: java

Только начал изучать Java. Дали простенькую задачку, но чтобы при этом программа реагировала на ошибки пользователя.Задача вот:Составить линейную программу, печатающую значение true, если указанное высказывание является истинным, и false — в противном случае:
Сумма двух первых цифр заданного четырехзначного числа равна сумме двух его последних цифр.
Я сделал так,что изначально число введённое с клавиатуры типа String.Потом переводиться в массив Char. И вот собственно мой вопрос. Возможно ли чтобы после введения в консоли 4 символа массива программа автоматически запускалась (без Enter).

Answer (score 3):

Поскольку не совсем ясно, что именно вы имеете ввиду под запуском программы я отвечу на две возможных интерпретации вопроса.

### Управление терминалом до запуска

Если вы предполагаете, что операционная система запустит JVM в момент когда вы напишете последний символ следующей команды:

```
$ java com.example.Main 4532
```

то к сожалению это сделать невероятно сложно и сильно зависит от предоставляемых настроек терминала операционной системы и из вашей программы вы не сможете это сделать, поскольку управление вашей программе не передастся до тех пор пока она не будет запущена, а изменить вы хотите именно поведение запуска.

### Управление терминалом внутри программы

Теперь рассмотрим другой вариант. Допустим вы запускаете свое приложение аргументов, после чего пользователь видит предложение ввести четырехзначное число:

```
$ java com.example.Main
Enter 4-digit number:
```

И в этом случае мы рассматриваем задачу запустить обработку входных данных как только пользователь введет 4 цифры.

**Короткий ответ** звучит как "Да, это возможно". В принципе в программировании любое поведение возможно реализовать. Однако ответ будет **не кроссплатформенный**, пока вы не позаботитесь об этом, или же не используете библиотеку, которая уже об этом заботится. Например [jCurses](https://sourceforge.net/projects/javacurses/) предоставит необходимый функционал.

Почему я вообще говорю о том, что надо предусматривать конкретную платформу? Дело в том, что System.in соединяется с системным терминалом, который в большинстве случаев по умолчанию реализует буферизацию ввода, то есть передает программе входные данные после ввода *enter* от пользователя.

Если здоровое любопытство программиста ведет вас к тому, чтобы таки реализовать желаемое вами поведение, давайте напишем наивный (и, стало быть, самый короткий) рабочий вариант, с которого можно начать удовлетворять любопытство.

Сходу я могу написать вместе с вами программу, которая будет реализовывать необходимое вам поведение на unix-подобных системах. Заранее приношу извинения за игнорирование каноничных правил обработки ошибок систем ввода/вывода: я уверен, что вы в состоянии самостоятельно дополнить программу до безопасного варианта.

Начнем с реализации метода считывания **n** цифр из потока:

```
private static char[] readInRawMode(int numberOfCharacters, InputStream stream) throws IOException {
    char [] result = new char[numberOfCharacters];

    InputStreamReader is = new InputStreamReader(stream);

    int characterCount = 0;
    while (characterCount < numberOfCharacters) {
        char aChar = (char) is.read();

        if (aChar < '0' || aChar > '9') { //проверим, что это цифра
            continue;
        }

        result[characterCount] = aChar;
        characterCount++;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Если мы сейчас используем этот метод в программе, например `readInRawMode(4, System.in)`, то вызов `is.read()` заблокируется до тех пор, пока пользователь не нажмет `enter`. Для того чтобы избежать этого поведения, нам нужно перевести текущий системый терминал в режим `raw` перед вызовом метода и вернуть его в режим `cooked` после завершения метода обработки. В режиме `raw` терминал не повторяет символы вводимые пользователем на экране (как при введении пароля в терминале) и мы должны сделать это самостоятельно. Более того, в raw терминал перестанет реагировать на спец символы включая символ перевода каретки и `enter` от пользователя также будет игнорироваться и не отображаться до тех пор пока он не введет необходимое количество цифр. Это как раз то поведение которое нас устраивает.

Собирая все описанное вместе мы получим что то вроде подобного:

```
package com.alex;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        System.out.print("Enter 4-digit number : ");

        char [] input = interactiveRead();
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("User input: " + Arrays.toString(input));
    }

    private static char[] interactiveRead() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        String[] raw = {"/bin/sh", "-c", "stty raw </dev/tty"}; //команда перевода текущего терминала в режим raw
        String[] cooked = {"/bin/sh", "-c", "stty cooked </dev/tty"}; //команда перевода текущего терминала в режим cooked
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(raw);
        p.waitFor();//ожидаем перевода терминала
        try {
            return readInRawMode(4, System.in);
        } finally {
            p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cooked); //возвращаем терминал к изначальному виду вне зависимости от ошибок
            p.waitFor();
        }
    }

    private static char[] readInRawMode(int numberOfCharacters, InputStream stream) throws IOException {
        char [] result = new char[numberOfCharacters];

        InputStreamReader is = new InputStreamReader(stream);

        int characterCount = 0;
        while (characterCount < numberOfCharacters) {
            char aChar = (char) is.read();

            if (aChar < '0' || aChar > '9') {
                continue;
            }

            System.out.print(aChar); // повторяем "правильный" символ на экране, чтобы пользователь понял что он все делает правильно

            result[characterCount] = aChar;
            characterCount++;
        }

        return result;
    }

}
```

### Обсуждение и замечания

В действительноси, в большинстве случаев нет смысла писать сложную логику "богатого" взаимодействия пользователя с терминалом. Это дает сильное усложнение логики приложения (то, что мы описали только что недостаточно: необходимо позаботиться об ошибках выполнения и управляющих комманд таких как ^C в терминале), а профит минимальный: в современном мире пользователи предпочитают графические интерфейсы, а люди привыкшие работать с терминалом и так поймут что происходит и что именно нужно вводить: это люди технического склада ума.

Также хочу заметить, что написанное приложение заточено на запуск из терминала руками и только тогда оно будет корректно работать. В случае запуска через IDE ее родной терминал не переведется в необходимый режим, поскольку используется не стандартный системный терминал, а его обертка, которая также реализует буферизацию. Надеюсь это делает еще более понятной сложно написания универсального решения для вашей задачи.

Comment: Спасибо большое за подробный ответ!)

Comment: За такие ответы я полюбил StackOverFlow. Спасибо, было интересно почитать!